# Is there a way to avoid overriding of values when reading from multiple property files using spring with same keys?

Tags: spring

In our application, we have two property files which are available in classpath. Both the property files will have same keys but different values. I would like to load values from both the property files on need basis. Could you please help me know how to achieve this in spring
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) and [PropertiesFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html).

Use this example class:

```java
public class PropertiesUtils {
    public static Properties propertiesOf(String... paths) {
        Resource[] locations = Arrays.stream(paths)
                .map(ClassPathResource::new)
                .toArray(ClassPathResource[]::new);
        return propertiesOf(locations);
    }

    public static Properties propertiesOf(Resource... resources) {
        PropertiesFactoryBean properties = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        properties.setLocations(resources);
        try {
            // force to load the properties
            properties.afterPropertiesSet();
            return properties.getObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
...
// path1/yyy.properties is relative to the root of the classpath
Properties yyy = PropertiesUtils.propertiesOf("somepath/yyy.properties");
Properties zzz = PropertiesUtils.propertiesOf("zzz.properties");
```